# Notepad++ split a line that starts with a string into rows on each space

Tags: notepad++, regex

I have some text that looks like this

```
Read the following aloud
Orange Mango Lemon Apple

Read the following aloud 
red yellow blue white green black purple
```

I need to split it to look like this

```
Read the following aloud
Orange
Mango
Lemon
Apple

Read the following aloud 
Red
Yellow
Blue
White
Green
Black
Purple
```

I've tried using regex but I can't select only the spaces. What I'm finding is I can select the whole line

Any pointers would be highly appreciated

Comment: Please share the regex that you tried that didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(\w+)\h+(?=.+(?:\R\R|\Z))`
- Replace with: `$1\n`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- *UNCHECK `. matches newline`*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(\w+)       # group 1, 1 or more word characters
\h+         # 1 or more horizontal spaces
(?=         # positive lookahead, make sure we have after:
    .+      # 1 or more any character but newline
    (?:     # start non capture group
      \R\R  # 2 linebreaks
     |      # OR
      \Z    # end of file
    )       # end group
)           # end lookahead
```

**Replacement:**

```
$1          # content of group 1
\n          # linefeed, you can use "\r\n"
```

**Result for given example:**

```
Read the following aloud
Orange
Mango
Lemon
Apple

Read the following aloud 
red
yellow
blue
white
green
black
purple
```

**Screen capture:**

[image]